# On High Sierra, how to make a writable disk image open a window automatically?

Tags: mac, dmg, high-sierra

I have some read-write disk images (some .dmg format, some in .sparseimage format) that I want to automatically open a Finder window to their base folders when I double-click them.  Up to now, I have been able to do that using the `bless` command, like:

```
sudo bless --folder dirPath --openfolder dirPath
```

but that no longer works as of High Sierra.  Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that Apple fixed this problem in High Sierra 10.13.4.